# How to swap an image with an existing image on a website using html.

Tags: html, image, swap, onmouseover, onmouseclick

I have 5 images on my web page. 4 are equal in size and one is much larger than the others. I was wondering how would I go about writing the code to swap and resize one of the smaller images on click to replace the larger one, simultaneously resizing the larger one to fit where the smaller one was.

I tried to use onmouseover="swagImage('image')" but that simply replaces the image with another. I was wondering how I could make the picture swap positions.

Comment: What is `swagImage()`? Please provide us your code.

Comment: If you would like some genuine help, please post all of your relevant HTML, CSS and Javascript/jQuery into a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you are looking for: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp
Look at the bottom example, it shows you how to change images.  Now, instead of the example swapping the src values of the two images should change the images in each spot.

I will leave changing sizes as an exercise for the reader, but it should work if you swap the width and height properities.

Comment: Please avoid linking to w3schools. This page is a very good reason not to.